# Goal in Google Analytics Destination, Begins with play.google.com does not convert

Tags: google-analytics, google-play, google-ads-api

I am wondering why my goal is not converting at all. It should have.

> Goal Type : Destination
>
> Goal Begins With : https://play.google.com and http://play.google.com

I have had a lot of views to my website but for some reason the goal does not convert at all. Due to this my google ad's App Install Campaign is stuck for

> Focus on conversions (Conversion Optimizer) - use CPA bids
>
> Unavailable because this campaign doesn't yet have conversion data.

Basically I need some conversions recorded before I can set Focus on app Installs on my google ads.

Answer (score 2):

It's not totally clear to me what domain you own, but I presume you don't own play.google.com. That means you won't be able to use it as a destination in goals.

Figure out what exact event you are trying to log as a goal. If that event can be defined as a URL on your base host address, then use it as a destination goal. If it can't be defined as a URL within your domain, then you'll have to log it as a different type of event.

Comment: I dont own play.google.com, thats right. I did not know that. How about if I create a bitly link for my app in play.google.com and give that here ?

Comment: @Siddharth GA can only log events that happen on a page in which you have tracking code installed. But since Google Play and Google Analytics are cousins, you can do some fancy GA integrations. See here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2956981?hl=en

Comment: I have set this up now, and I still get 'Unavailable because this campaign doesn't yet have conversion data.'

Comment: @Siddharth Give it 24 hours or so. It usually takes that long to refresh.